# html Javascript move image by onmouseover on <a> button

Tags: javascript, html, element, move, getelementbyid

I'm a stupid website creator, and I've got some problems with a javascript. I found a function on the internet and now i'm combining it with some more things.
But it doesn't work at all. I dont have much experience with javascript.

Javascript file:

```
function getOff(){z = this.ElementId;
 x = document.getElementById('button_shadow' + z);
 return x.offsetLeft;}

function move_right(value){var y = getOff();
 x.style.left = y + value;}
```

html:

```
<img src="img/button_shadow.png" class="button_shadow" style="top: 218px; left: 5px;" id="button_shadow1">
<img src="img/button_shadow.png" class="button_shadow" style="top: 259px; left: 5px;" id="button_shadow2">

<script src="js/button_shadow_move.js"></script>
<a class="tlacitko_bok" style="top: 0px;" href="o_klubu.html" id="1" onmouseover="getOff(); move_right(5);">O klubu</a>
<a class="tlacitko_bok" style="top: 41px;" href="fotogalerie.html" id="2" onmouseover="getOff(); move_right(5);">Fotogalerie</a>
```

css:

```
a.tlacitko_bok:hover{margin-left: 5px;}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify and improve your code. You can only leave this one function:

```
function move_right(obj, value) {
    var x = document.getElementById('button_shadow' + obj.id);
    x.style.left = x.offsetLeft + value + 'px';
}
```

and use it in HTML like this:

```
<a id="1" onmouseover="move_right(this, 5);" ...>O klubu</a>
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/efu8n/

You mistakes: you should use `id` property, not `ElementId`. Also context inside your function if you invoke them like this is going to be Window, not the target element you interact with. So you can simply pass reference object `this` to use for retrieving `id`.